# Power set of $X$ has no divisors of $0$

Tags: ring-theory

For any positive integer $n$, let $X_n$ be a set of size $n$, and let $P_n$ be the power set of $X_n$. For which values of $n$ does $(P_n, \cup, \cap)$ have divisors of zero?

Comment: Have you checked out the small values of $n$ yet? You say you've tried the question until you've done that!

Comment: Here, two sets $A,B$ are considered zero divisors if $A \cap B = \emptyset$, but $A,B \neq \emptyset$?

Comment: @CXB Did I edit your post correctly?

Comment: @Arbuja yes thank you :)

Comment: but what does the set Xn consist of?

Comment: *but what does the set Xn consist of?* by your hypothesis, it is a set with $n$ elements... any such set will do, there is nothing special about which one you pick beyond how many elements it has. I suggest you stare at Bemte's comment above until you "get it" for sure.